# How to assign tasks to a project in access?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

```
    UPDATE table1, (select top 1 [ID],chef,formateur,techni from table1 order by Num desc) 
AS x SET table2.ID = x.[ID], table2.Nom = x.[chef], table2.Nom = x.[formateur],
table2.Nom = x.[techni]
WHERE table2.mission="chef" and table2.mission="Formateur" and table2.mission="techni" ;

returns
table2                                            table 1
 ID | mission      |Nom|                ID |chef|Formateur|techni|   
 --------------------------------           ----------------------------
  1 |  chef        |   |                 1 |nom1|    nom2 | nom3|  
  2 |  Formateur   |   |               **Result**  
  3 |  techni      |   |                   ID | mission   | Nom|
                                         --------------------------  
                                            1 |  chef     | nom1|      
                                            2 |  Formateur| nom2|
                                            3 |  techni   | nom3|
```

1. I want to assign the name of table1 in table 2.
   Please i need your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
insert into table3(ID, categorie, DATE, Projets)
select ID, categorie, DATE, Projects, 'projetX'
from table2
```

**UPDATE**

I think this answers your updated question (your table and column names are inconsistent, so I'm not sure):

```
update TACHES_TEMPLATE, (select top 1 [Libelle Projects] from Projects order by ID desc) x
set TACHES_TEMPLATE.projets = x.[Libelle Projects]
```

Comment: I have 3 tables, and the field of table 1 "Libelle Projet" it does not have the same name as the fields of table 2 and 3

Comment: That doesn't matter.  Table1 isn't really involved in your question (you're just setting the Projets column equal to the string 'projetX').  If this isn't what you're trying to do, you'll need to clarify your question.

Comment: For example in table 1 we have id and libelle project and date, and in table 2 we have id, categorie, projects, and date.and in table 3 it is like table 2 but just it is empty . I want to assign the value "Project X" to the column of table3 "Projectcs" or table 2 "projects".

Comment: I understand.  That's what my answer does.

Comment: I have to modify the question thank you can you help me??

Comment: Thank you well chef

Comment: hello, please i changed the quetions can you help me ?

Comment: Don't keep changing the question.  Post new questions.